Change language whilst holding a key
General question for Windows.
I have my keyboard in Windows set up for English and Hebrew.
I want to be able, while working in English, that when I hold some key, and only whilst holding it, the keyboard changes to Hebrew.
Similar to holding shift for capslock.
Is there an option for this in windows? If no, what's the best approach into developing such a feature?

Windows allows you to switch between keyboards based on settings in the Language section of the Control panel. But I am not aware that it switches back when you release the key(s).
